# Error while using 127.0.0.1 for connecting to mysql for a privilleged root user

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with connecting to mysql usung 127.0.0.1 for host :

```
mysql -uroot -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
but when i change 127.0.0.1 to localhost its ok.

i checked privilleges for root user with:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
```

and that is :

```
 root          | %                       
 root          | 127.0.0.1 
 root          | localhost
```

why i got this error while root user has privilleges from both 127.0.0.1 and local host ? and how can i fix that to connect to mysql using 127.0.0.1 for host?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using the special hostname `localhost` your client will connect using a local socket, not a network socket, unless you took special preparations. So there is a difference.

Take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

So this sounds like your mysql server does not bind to the loopback network interface or does not listen to network connections at all.

Comment: how to check its bind to loopback or its listening to network connections?

Comment: The usual test for such thing is to use the telnet cli utility: `telnet localhost 3306`. This connects to the mysql standard port with a general two way connection. You should get some greeting string from mysql _if it can connect_, a timeout or a denied/blocked if it cannot connect. If this indeed is the issue (no connection possible), then you have to check your configuration of the mysql server.

Comment: i tested with : telnet 127.0.0.1 3306 and connected and i tried telnet localhost 3306 and the output was :  Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.

Comment: Ah, so localhost is resolved to the local IPV6 `::1` instead of the IPV4 address `127.0.0.1` address at your system... So probably this is where you want to start reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-local-connections.html It explains how to setup your mysql server to allow IPV6 connections. This would prevent you from having to modify your system setup. I _may_ be that you have to add that IPV6 address to your permission setup inside mysql. But at first glance this looks more like it is a networking problem, the mysql server not binding to that address.

Comment: my localhost is resolving to 127.0.0.1. i dont want to set ipv6 and it seems it resolves correctly to localhost :  Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to localhost but when i try : mysql -uroot -p -h 127.0.0.1  the output is :  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES). and the root user has all privilleges in both localhost and 127.0.0.1 hosts when i check with select user,host from mysql.user; and output is:   root   | %                       
 root          | 127.0.0.1 
 root          | localhost

Comment: Before you wrote this: `telnet localhost 3306 and the output was : Trying ::1... `